# Visual Studio 2008 upgrade to 2010 (in-place, solutions, etc)?

Tags: visual-studio

I have Visual Studio 2008 installed on a Windows 2008 Enterprise Server. I am thinking of upgrading to Visual Studio 2010 and wanted to know if this would be an in-place upgrade, or do I have to completely uninstalled Visual Studio 2008 then install 2010? What about all my solutions, do I have to upgrade them to 2010 as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have both installed, and use them seperatly.

And only upgrade the projects you want.

Comment: Just to add to this, use your source control to keep the old 2008 version if for some reason you need to rollback.

Comment: I do use SVN on all my code. But reversing the project is not a problem, visual studio actualy takes a backup.  Asuming your not gonna change .NET version downgrading visual studio will be easy.

Answer (score 1):

To add to EKS there are some instances where you **have to have** side by side installation.  Unmanaged C++/CLI code projects upgraded to VS2010 are forced to use .NET 4.0.  So if you require to C+/CLI with .NET 3.5 or lower then you have to keep VS2008 around.

This is an issue that bit me and is really annoying.

Here is a [Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/framework-multi-targeting-for-vc-projects/) that describes the work around you have to make in order to use .NEt 3.5 etc and C+/CLI in VS2010